# snmp logs location

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

```
DEBUGMSGTL(("","Initializing scalar integer.  Default value = %d\n"));

snmp_log(LOG_ERR,"fscanf failed in temp fun(),errno:\n");
```

with these log I want all logs from startinn of snmp service to end of it. But don't know where to see.

where these logs are going to be saved ? I am using NET-SNMP version: 5.7.2.rc1

while installation I have not given any location in

Location to write logfile  &  Location to write persistent information.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile-time option [--with-logfile](http://www.pavius.net/2011/02/compiling-net-snmp-for-embedded-linux-using-the-eldk/). Your package maintainer should document the default for itself.

Comment: As I have mentioned I have given "NULL"  with this option... So can I get any default location ?

Comment: did you install it from source or was it in a package?

Comment: I have downloaded tar.gz first and then Installed it with ./configure,make,make install commands

Comment: Ok, I'll do the same and deliver my findings as a comment in a few hours.

Comment: I haven't yet built it, because I have no idea how I can test SNMP on an Android tablet, but perusing the source, it looks like it logs to the option specified with the -L option. To log to a file, pass -Lf [filename] on start of the daemon and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: -Lf does not provide snmp_log... it just provides logs of starting and running snmpd

Answer (score 0):

In order to do debugging the following function need to be set

```
snmp_set_do_debugging(1);
```